Language and Mind
I'm creating my own language with a minimal number of words and a maximum of grammar, allowing words to be formed using prefixes, suffixes, and other methods. I'm curious to know how much my thinking might change if I learn to think in such an artificial language. To rephrase: will a person who thinks in two or more languages that are not similar to each other have better thinking skills and be better at conveying their own thoughts?

Great idea. But in this direction you should consider learning the language of mathematics and programming if you still haven't.

There are studies into the cognitive benefits of being bilingual (for example). I'm not sure if philosophy specifically would have much to say about it (or whatever it says might be superseded by scientific exploration of the topic).

Why don't you go with Esperanto instead of inventing your own language? "Bilinguals exhibit increased executive function and executive control, including better performance than monolinguals in some problem-solving tasks, especially those requiring self-monitoring and the inhibition of irrelevant information." However, negative effects include "deficit in lexical access and retrieval and worse performance in speech production tasks, as well as diminished metacognitive efficiency." Oliveira.

Also see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructed_language otherwise the question seems to broad to answer.


will a person who thinks in two or more languages that are not similar to each other have better thinking skills and be better at conveying their own thoughts? The research on linguistic relativity seems to indicate language can influence thought, but it does not seem to make any major difference. Someone seeking to improve their thinking skill and expression can likely get better results for the same effort with more conventional training. Being competent in the technical languages of maths, given natural sciences, or programming lang



The Limits of my language are the limits of my world
Wittgenstein

This quote is well known and over used, especially in circles like this site but unless it is more detailed and nuanced it perhaps lacks convincing power.

I cannot speak my thought without thinking my speech
Roland Barthes

So Barthes + Wittgenstein pour cold water on your proposal in your proposed form but they offer encouragement in a related alternate direction: Your thinking cannot change much under the conditions of your own invented languages because your own invented languages will inherently only ossify your already stabilized thought processes, but learning utterly new languages is a powerful benchpress for the brain “muscle”.

The American programmer would profit more from learning, say, Latin than from learning yet another programming language
E. W. Dijkstra
(a founding father of computer science)

Also:

With English being computing science's Esperanto, colleagues with English as their native tongue often feel somewhat guilty about what they regard as their undeserved advantage over most foreigners. Their feeling of guilt is misplaced, because the advantage is ours. It is very helpful to have to do your work in what always remains a foreign language, as it forces you to express yourself more consciously. (About the most excellent prose written in our field that I can think of, is to be found in aforementioned ALGOL 60 Report: its editor had the great advantage of being, besides brilliant, a Dane. I have always felt that much of the stability and well-deserved fame of ALGOL 60 could be traced down directly to the inexorable accuracy of Peter Naur's English.)

Linguists naturally have more data towards this than typical philosophers. The goto standard is of course Sapir & Whorf but it may be more helpful to take current examples.

Languages differ not in what they may convey but what they must convey
Roman Jakobson

See how gender neutrality in inherently more gendered languages like Spanish fares.
Random other evidences for linguistic relativity:

Lera Boroditsky is one good source.

Here is another collection.

Tone languages like Chinese conduce to children having a significantly greater chance towards absolute pitch

Bilingualism postpones Alzheimer by about 4 years


